# TSQL skipping over exec statement without running stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that normally runs fine. However, for one record as I walk through the stored procedure it is "skipping" a line without running it.

```
if not exists ( select * ... ) begin
    exec @Result = InsertRecord_A @AccountNo, @ID, @EventID;
    if @Result <> 0 return @Result;

    -- Do something else
    insert into ...
    select ...
end
```

That line, `exec @Result...` is being skipped in this case. Normally it launches the procedure `InsertRecord_A` but I can't get it to run on this record.

Any ideas?

Update: There is the following error message:

```
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure InsertRecord_A, Line 0
Procedure or function 'InsertRecord_A' expects parameter '@EventID', which was not supplied.
```

What is odd about the error message, is when walking through it, @EventID shows it has a value of 460 which is correct.

Comment: Does it successfully evaluate the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause for this particular record?

Comment: Yes it does. After it evaluates that, the script walks to the next line (exec @Result...). Then when I tell it to walk to the next line, it jumps to (if @Result...) instead of into the procedure.

Comment: In that case, did you verify all the variables have expected data?

Comment: Yes, AccountNo, ID, and EventID have data as expected.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `InsertRecord_A` proc?

Comment: There is an error message -
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure InsertRecord_A, Line 0
Procedure or function 'InsertRecord_A' expects parameter 'EventID', which was not supplied.

However, when walking through it, it displays 460 (which is the correct EventID) as being set for the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the parameters to the correct values, rather than passing them by ordinal position and hoping they're in the correct order:

```
exec @Result = InsertRecord_A @AccountNo = @AccountNo, @ID = @ID, @EventID = @EventID;
```

This is of course assumes that your `InsertRecord_A` procedure does take 3 procedures with the same names as your variables.

If you're not sure about this, you can run `exec sp_help InsertRecord_A` or look in the `sys.parameters` table to check what they're called.

Comment: we're thinking on the same lines that this could be to do with relying on passing parameters by position rather than explicitly naming them.

Comment: It was my mistake. The InsertRecord_A had been modified to take another AccountNo with a very similar name. The error message was being misread as the procedure was filling in variables in the wrong order and an "AccountNo" was being left blank on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I think @SchmitzIT was asking for the actual SQL code (CREATE PROCEDURE etc) for procedure InsertRecord_A, rather than the error code.
Just a guess: The error you're getting is one I've had in the past when I've accidentally changed the number of parameters in a procedure definition.  If your proc had been changed like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertREcord_A @ExtraParameter int, @AccountNo int,@ID int,@EventID int
```

then it'll be looking for an @EventID parameter in position 4.  The fact that you're passing a valid parameter called @EventID in position 3 will not help!  In this situation, the fact that the passed-in parameter at position 3, and the expected parameter at position 4, are both called @EventID, is just confusing.

(This is why I always prefix parameters with p in procedure definitions)

Comment: Thanks sebt, both you and Bridge gave me the clue I had skipped over. I had modified the number of parameters and wasn't thinking of it as the error message was being read deceptively.